# Place a vector randomly inside a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, random

How can I place the vector `a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)` in a ramdom position in the matrix `m<-matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)`?

The vector has to be together:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    5    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    6    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

And it has to be horizontally, vertically or diagonally
I have tried:

```
start = sample.int(length(m), 1)
m[start:(start+length(a)-1)] = a
```

But it cannot take place the following:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    5    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    6    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    3    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    4    0    0    0     0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sample a 1d index of the same size as `a` and then assign the vector to `m` at those indices:

```
m[sample.int(length(m), length(a))] <- a
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    0    6    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    4    0    0    0     0
# [3,]    0    3    0    1    0    0    0    0    5     0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2     0
# [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

---

If the vector needs to be continuous, you can sample the start index, and then assign with range index:

```
start = sample.int(length(m), 1)
m[start:(start+length(a)-1)] = a

m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [5,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [6,]    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [7,]    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [8,]    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [9,]    5    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#[10,]    6    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Comment: Thaks, but I meant the vector to be together as in the edit I added

Comment: Thanks again, but with that code, I only obtain the vector horizontally, besides it happens the following: